# Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to // failed: Connection timed out: connect

Tags: java, apache, servlets

i'm so done i tried everything thing but it doesn't work, here is my problem,
I'm trying to send some files from a machine to another, the idea is to create a servlet on the destination machine, run it on server and waiting for any clients to be connected with, the client and the servlet code works perfectly in a lan network type, but when it comes to a wan network type, i get this exception

Exception in thread "main" org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 192.168.1.12:8080 [/192.168.1.12] failed: Connection timed out: connect

these are consecutively the client and the servlet code

```
import java.io.File;

    import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.entity.mime.MultipartEntityBuilder;
    import org.apache.http.entity.mime.content.FileBody;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
    import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

    public class UploadClient
    {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception 
{
    String test="C:/Users/Soufiane/Desktop/Dossier/";
    if (test.equalsIgnoreCase("")) 
    {
        System.out.println("Files path not given");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();
    try
    {

          // On cree une connection avec la servlet qui va recevoir les fichiers
      HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://192.168.1.12:8080/soufiane/haha");

   MultipartEntityBuilder multipartEntityBuilder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
   FileBody bin;

   // le nom du chemin de repertoire contenant les fichiers à tranmettre doit s   terminer par un "\". 
        if(test.endsWith("/"))
        {
            File file = new File(test);
            String[] files = file.list();
            for(int i=0;i<files.length;i++)
            {
                bin = new FileBody(new File(test + files[i]));
                multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("bin_"+i, bin);
            }
        }
        // si le nom du chemin de repertoire contenant les fichiers à tranmettre ne se terminer par un "\" alors on 
        // considere que c'est un nom qui correspond à un fichier à transmettre seul.
        else
        {
            bin = new FileBody(new File(test));
            multipartEntityBuilder.addPart("bin", bin);
        }

        HttpEntity reqEntity = multipartEntityBuilder.build();
        httppost.setEntity(reqEntity);

        System.out.println("executing request " + httppost.getRequestLine());

        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        try {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
                HttpEntity resEntity = response.getEntity();
                if (resEntity != null) {
                    System.out.println("Response content length: "
                            + resEntity.getContentLength());
                }
                System.out.println("Response result: "+EntityUtils.toString(resEntity));

                //  EntityUtils.consume(resEntity);

        }
        finally 
        {
            response.close();
        }

        } 
        finally 
        {
         httpclient.close();
        }
       }
      }
```

and this is the servlet code

```
                import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
                import java.io.File;
                 import java.io.IOException;
                  import java.io.PrintWriter;
              import java.util.Iterator;
             import java.util.List;
                   import javax.servlet.ServletException;
             import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
             import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
             import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItem;
             import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileItemFactory;
              import org.apache.commons.fileupload.FileUploadException;
             import org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItemFactory;
                import org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.ServletFileUpload;


    public class UploadServlet extends HttpServlet
    {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
      public UploadServlet() 
     {
    super();
}

/**
 * Destruction of the servlet. <br>
 */


 /**
 * The doGet method of the servlet. <br>
 *
 * This method is called when a form has its tag value method equals to get.
 * 
 * @param request the request send by the client to the server
 * @param response the response send by the server to the client
 * @throws ServletException if an error occurred
 * @throws IOException if an error occurred
 */

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\">");
    out.println("<HTML>");
    out.println("<HEAD><TITLE>A Servlet</TITLE></HEAD>");
    out.println("<BODY>");
    out.print("This is ");
    out.print(this.getClass());
    out.println(", using the GET method");
    out.println("  </BODY>");
    out.println("</HTML>");
    out.flush();
    out.close(); 
}

/*
 * The doPost method of the servlet. <br>

 * This method is called when a form has its tag value method equals to post.

 * @param request the request send by the client to the server.
 * @param response the response send by the server to the client.
 * @throws ServletException if an error occurred
 * @throws IOException if an error occurred
 */


public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
    ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
    upload.setSizeMax(1000000000);
    String filename="";
    String responseText = "";
    List<FileItem> fileItems;
    try 
    {
        fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);
        // Process the uploaded items
        @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
        Iterator iter = fileItems.iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext())
        {
            FileItem item = (FileItem) iter.next();
            filename = item.getName();
            File file = new File("C:\\Users\\Soufiane\\Desktop"+filename);
            item.write(file);
       responseText = responseText+"\n"+"uploading file "+filename+" succeed";
         }
    } 
    catch (FileUploadException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally 
    {
        if(responseText.isEmpty())
            responseText = "uploading files failed";
    }
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setContentLength(responseText.length());
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print(responseText);        
    out.flush();
    out.close();
}

/*
 * Initialization of the servlet. <br>
 *
 * @throws ServletException if an error occurs
 *
 *
 *
/*
 * Initialization of the servlet. <br>
 *
 * @throws ServletException if an error occurs
 */
    }

        i have an exame about this next monday, so plz help me
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you misunderstood how network addresses works.

192.168.1.12:8080 is an address from Private Network Address Pool. You should use your's external address (can be obtained by e.g http://ipaddress.com/). But not all ISP provides external address (called also as public IP).

#### References

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network